# which generic html5 root elements can i claim for css?

Tags: css, html, article

For a simple business-card-style web-page, it seems possible to use the `html` element in CSS to specify `background-color` for your document, and add some fancy `border` / `margin: auto` / `padding: 1em` through `body`.  Looks nice in Google Cache, BTW, which would have their header within your body, all nice and fancy, just as it was meant to be.

However, the above seems to conflict with the Internet Archive Wayback Machine, with their interface being overlaid on top of your `body` (doesn't look very bad, but not the best).  Also, the `body {margin: auto}` part (used to centre the body element) gets lost through the Yandex cache.

We can add a `div`, and switch the CSS rule from `body` to `div`, and from `html` to `body` (and it'll look perfect in Yandex cache), but then it starts conflicting with Google Cache, looking really weird; Internet Archive is somewhat better, but their own `div`'s do get dangled with your stylesheets, too, looking quite unintended.

You could argue that I should use an `id` attributes, but then it's not like it's guaranteed that it's not going to conflict with something else again, too, plus the style will not be generic anymore.

What would be the best approach if I want to stick with standard html5 elements?  Perhaps still use `body` (or `html`?) to set the background colour through CSS, and an `article` or `section` for the box element with the border and central position?

Comment: Just my two cents: I wouldn’t even bother with that. All such caches have their limitations – I’ve seen anything from broken images to completely missing formatting. I’d assume these are rarely used by regular users anyway. And if I wanted to provide a “perfect” cached version of my own website (f.e. as a designer wanting to show previous versions of my portfolio), then I would provide those myself, and not rely on external services.

Comment: @CBroe, wow, I think you give up too quickly! :-)  I'm basically deciding whether `article` or `section` is the element to use on my sites like [sanctioned](http://sanctioned.ru/) and [dedi](http://dedi.su/) etc.

Comment: btw, i've realised that it's also possible to move the style element within my article/section.  however, is there any way to affect the outside `body` from within such `article` or `section`, with CSS alone, that is?

Comment: These caches probably overwrite some styles on the `html` and `body` elements, in order to display their own headers correctly. So any styles you put on elements inside body will probably not be affected at all. However, there is no way of styling “inside out” with CSS.

Comment: Why would you worry about how old versions of your site will look like? The Internet Archive is for sites that aren't up anymore, or that have changed their designs. Anyone who wants to visit your site will visit your active site directly, not via the Internet Archive.

Comment: @TylerH "changed their designs", exactly. So I want to see what the site used to _look_ like, not just what the content was.

Comment: @MrLister While I was addressing the OP, it's fine if you are curious about such things, but it's *not* a concern of the business whatsoever to maintain their old design on *someone else's* server.

Answer (score 2):

The Internet Wayback Machine [does not guarantee](https://archive.org/about/faqs.php#18)<sup>1</sup> [complete archives](http://www.archive.org/about/faqs.php#12http://www.archive.org/about/faqs.php#12)<sup>2</sup>:

> Please note that while we try to archive an entire site, this is not always possible....Additionally some sites do not archive well and we cannot fix that.

...

> Not every date for every site archived is 100% complete.

So there is no way to guarantee that the archived site's CSS will always display as it did when live or even always be available. The file(s) might not get indexed on a particular date. Nor is there any way to ensure future changes to the Wayback Machine's own CSS (or how they handle archived CSS) won't change and cause other issues.